# Nativescript CameraPlus preview too zoomed in

Tags: nativescript, android-camera, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

I'm using [Camera Plus](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus) with Nativescript Vue. The camera preview is very zoomed in, but when I take a photo it comes out normal. This only happens on Android. 
Anyone out there who have experience with this plugin and knows what the issue might be? Is there a way to control the zoom?

I have also noticed if I set the height of the preview to around 300, it's not zoomed in, but the higher the height, the more zoomed in it gets.

My implementation:

app.js

```
import Camera from './components/Camera';
const CameraPlus = require("@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus");

Vue.registerElement('CameraPlus', () => CameraPlus.CameraPlus);

const app = new Vue({
  template: `
        <Frame>
            <Camera />
        </Frame>`,
  components: {
    Camera,
  },
});

app.$start();
```

camera.vue

```
<template lang="html">
  <Page>
      <CameraPlus></CameraPlus>
  </Page>
</template>
```

Tested on Android 9 and 10 with Camera Plus v3.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I registered this issue [here](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus/issues/143).

This is actualy due to the Android's [native implementation](https://github.com/triniwiz/fancycamera) used by nativescript-camera-plus. It's named `FancyCamera` and developed in Kotlin language. Since new release 3.1.0 of CameraPlus uses new FancyCamera version as well, which has a new implementation using new Android camerax library (for android api 21+). With theat, the new plugin has the zoom issue is fixed.

However, at the moment I'm writing, the new implementation has bugs, which I'm tryingto fix, as explained [here](https://github.com/triniwiz/fancycamera/issues/12). Help is welcome.